# How set class to input on error using jQuery-validation-engine

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

I'm using the jquery-validation-engine plugin and after validate I need to add a class to the inputs with the error promt to add for example a red border or something like that, is there a way using the plugin configuration to setup this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I alsow use that same plugin.

Do you have the last verion off the plug-in ?
In the file: **jquery.validationEngine.js**

you will find almost at the bottom:

```
InvalidFields: [],
    onFieldSuccess: false,
    onFieldFailure: false,
    onSuccess: false,
    onFailure: false,
    addSuccessCssClassToField: false,
    addFailureCssClassToField: false,
```

These are the 'master' settings for the options you are looking for.
My current setup is like:

```
        InvalidFields: [],
    onFieldSuccess: true,
    onFieldFailure: true,
    onFormSuccess: false,
    onFormFailure: false,
    addSuccessCssClassToField: 'inputbox-success',
    addFailureCssClassToField: 'inputbox-error',
```

And then the two css classes in youre css file ( 'inputbox-error' & 'inputbox-succes').

This works just fine over here..
Good Luck...

And if you have any more question about this plugin or other functions off it just ask .. :P

Greets,
Marco

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to add icon before error message.